# How to click on navigation bar using selenium web driver with python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, office365

using the office 365 navbar, I try to click on the user icon to enter another mailbox, but selenium does not recognize it by id, class_name or xpath?

```py
elem6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="O365_MeFlexPane_ButtonID"]')
elem6.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

html tag

```html
<button type="button" class="o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365button ms-bgc-nlr ms-fcl-b o365cs-spo-topbarMenuOpen" role="menuitem" title="Carlos Loayza Cuestas" id="O365_MeFlexPane_ButtonID" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Use la flecha hacia abajo para utilizar el panel Mi cuenta para ver y editar su cuenta y cerrar la sesión"><div class="o365cs-mfp-header"> <div class="o365cs-mfp-header-displayname o365cs-rsp-tn-hide o365cs-mfp-header-displayname-wrap o365cs-display-none"> <span class="" role="presentation">Carlos Loayza Cuestas</span> </div> <div class="o365cs-nav-button o365cs-mfp-header-img"> <div class="o365cs-mfp-doughboy-container"> <span class="ms-bgc-nt ms-fcl-w o365cs-mfp-doughboy o365cs-mfp-circular-small owaimg ms-Icon ms-Icon--Contact ms-icon-font-size-52" aria-hidden="true"> </span> </div> <div class="o365cs-mfp-textboy o365cs-mfp-circular-small" style=""><div class="" style=""><div style="background-color: rgb(118, 118, 118); outline-color: rgb(118, 118, 118);">CC</div></div></div> <div style="display: none;"></div> <div class="o365cs-mfp-header-img-container o365cs-mfp-circular-small" style="display: none;"><img aria-hidden="true" src="service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=carlos.loayza@telefonica.com&amp;UA=0&amp;size=HR64x64&amp;sc=1559170428032"></div> <div autoid="__Microsoft_O365_ShellG2_MeFlexHeaderButton_Owa_templates_cs_0" class="o365cs-mfp-presenceButton ms-Icon--skypeCheck o365cs-mfp-skypeAvailable"></div> </div> </div><div class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenitems"> <span class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenCount ms-fcl-w ms-bgc-tdr" style="display: none;"></span> <span class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenCount owaimg ms-Icon--starburst ms-icon-font-size-12 ms-fcl-w ms-bgc-tdr" style="display: none;"> </span> </div></button>
```

python gives me the following result

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wcondorp\Videos\Selenium\prueba.py", line 80, in <module>
    elem6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="O365_MeFlexPane_ButtonID"]') #mail, onedrive, calendaria
  File "C:\Users\wcondorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\wcondorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\wcondorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\wcondorp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="O365_MeFlexPane_ButtonID"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Could you please attach the "Generated" content of your HTML? Because sometimes classes you entered in button changes when the plugins load. Or maybe it is inside an iframe, which makes difficult to find.

Comment: Did you mean content generated by CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Expected Conditions to wait for the element present using below code.

```
ele =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='O365_MeFlexPane_ButtonID']")))
ele.click()
```

If you are referring to the below button

[image]

Try with below xpath.

```
//div[@id='meInitialsButton']
```

Or you can also use the below xpath.

```
//div[@id='O365_MainLink_MePhoto']
```

Comment: Does it even make a sense to use xpath , when all you are doing is to have id in your xpath. ID has already precedence.